# HTTP client for JSTL

Tags: java, tomcat, proxy, jstl, httpclient

Currently i'm using JSTL  tag to get the URL from third party API. for this i have added the standard-1.0.6.jar in the classpath. I used tomcat server.

I would like to know how this  really works technically. Which HTTP client is used by c:import? whether there is separate http client for JSTL built inside standard.jar, or will it use http client used by tomcat server?

If i need to access the internet to get the same third party API using a internet proxy server, which part of HTTP client i need to modify (in standard.jar for any jstl http client or in tomcat httpclient)?

Comment: Almost certainly it just uses HttpURLConnection.

Answer (score 0):

It's just using the standard Java SE [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) class. You can use it in plain Java as follows:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com").openConnection();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
// ...
```

Or by the [`URL#openStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) shortcut:

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com").openStream();
// ...
```

The `InputStream` contains the HTTP response. Just read/write it to an arbitrary `OutputStream` the usual way.

#### See also:

- [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)